# Problems building up a simple DCDC converter in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to write a very simple model for a DCDC converter. For some reason, Dymola tells me that the "model is not well-posed" and overdetermined for Real elements.

It might be a quite simple problem but I can't see it!

Here's my code:

```
model DCDC

  extends Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.TwoPort;

  parameter Real demandedVoltage;

  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sensors.VoltageSensor sekVolt annotation (
      Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=270,
        origin={80,0})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sensors.CurrentSensor currentSensor annotation (
      Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,10},{10,-10}},
        rotation=270,
        origin={-50,-30})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SignalCurrent signalCurrent annotation (
      Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=270,
        origin={-50,30})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.ConstantVoltage constantVoltage(V=
        vehicleVoltage)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,10},{10,-10}},
        rotation=270,
        origin={50,30})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sensors.CurrentSensor currentSensor1 annotation (
      Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=270,
        origin={50,-30})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Division division
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{6,22},{-10,38}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Product product
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{8,-8},{-8,8}},
        rotation=270,
        origin={30,8})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Gain gain(k=-1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,22},{-36,38}})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sensors.VoltageSensor primVolt
                                                           annotation (
      Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,10},{10,-10}},
        rotation=270,
        origin={-80,0})));
equation 

  connect(currentSensor.p, signalCurrent.n) annotation (Line(
      points={{-50,-20},{-50,20}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(constantVoltage.n, currentSensor1.p) annotation (Line(
      points={{50,20},{50,-20}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(signalCurrent.p, p1) annotation (Line(
      points={{-50,40},{-50,50},{-100,50}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(currentSensor.n, n1) annotation (Line(
      points={{-50,-40},{-50,-50},{-100,-50}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(constantVoltage.p, p2) annotation (Line(
      points={{50,40},{50,50},{100,50}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(currentSensor1.n, n2) annotation (Line(
      points={{50,-40},{50,-50},{100,-50}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(primVolt.n, n1) annotation (Line(
      points={{-80,-10},{-80,-50},{-100,-50}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(primVolt.p, p1) annotation (Line(
      points={{-80,10},{-80,50},{-100,50}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(sekVolt.p, p2) annotation (Line(
      points={{80,10},{80,50},{100,50}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(sekVolt.n, n2) annotation (Line(
      points={{80,-10},{80,-50},{100,-50}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));

  connect(gain.y, signalCurrent.i) annotation (Line(
      points={{-36.8,30},{-43,30}},
      color={0,0,127},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(division.y, gain.u) annotation (Line(
      points={{-10.8,30},{-18.4,30}},
      color={0,0,127},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(currentSensor1.i, product.u2) annotation (Line(
      points={{40,-30},{25.2,-30},{25.2,-1.6}},
      color={0,0,127},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(sekVolt.v, product.u1) annotation (Line(
      points={{70,0},{62,0},{62,-10},{34.8,-10},{34.8,-1.6}},
      color={0,0,127},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(product.y, division.u1) annotation (Line(
      points={{30,16.8},{30,34.8},{7.6,34.8}},
      color={0,0,127},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(primVolt.v, division.u2) annotation (Line(
      points={{-70,0},{14,0},{14,20},{14,20},{14,25.2},{7.6,25.2}},
      color={0,0,127},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  annotation (
      Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false, extent={{-100,-100},{100,
            100}}), graphics), Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false,
          extent={{-100,-100},{100,100}}), graphics={
        Rectangle(
          extent={{-100,100},{100,-100}},
          lineColor={0,0,127},
          lineThickness=0.5,
          fillPattern=FillPattern.Solid,
          fillColor={215,215,215}),
        Line(
          points={{-100,100}},
          color={0,0,255},
          smooth=Smooth.None),
        Line(
          points={{-100,100},{-100,-100},{100,-100},{100,100},{-100,100}},
          color={0,0,127},
          thickness=0.5,
          smooth=Smooth.None),
        Line(
          points={{-100,-100},{100,100}},
          color={0,0,127},
          thickness=0.5,
          smooth=Smooth.None),
        Text(
          extent={{-60,80},{0,20}},
          lineColor={0,0,0},
          lineThickness=0.5,
          textString="DC"),
        Text(
          extent={{0,-20},{60,-80}},
          lineColor={0,0,0},
          lineThickness=0.5,
          textString="DC")}));
end DCDC;
```

Hopefully someone may figure out my problem here.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
After the answers I decided to change my model a bit since I need the converter for a hybrid (energy/power) supply. The resulting converter is given in the following code:

```
model DCDC2 "Component with two electrical ports, including current"

Real v_energy "Voltage drop over the energy port";
Real v_power "Voltage drop over the power port";
Real v_output "Voltage drop over the output port";
Real i_energy "Current flowing from pos. to neg. pin of the energy port";
Real i_power "Current flowing from pos. to neg. pin of the power port";
Real i_output "Current flowing from pos. to neg. pin of the output port";
Real p_energy;
Real p_power;
Real p_output;

parameter Real demandedVoltage;
parameter Real efficiency = 1;

Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.PositivePin pinP_Energy
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,50},{-90,70}})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.NegativePin pinN_Energy
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,-70},{-90,-50}})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.PositivePin pinP_Power
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,50},{110,70}})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.NegativePin pinN_Power
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-70},{110,-50}})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.PositivePin pinP_Output
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,80},{20,120}})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.NegativePin pinN_Output
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,-120},{20,-80}})));

equation 
  v_energy = pinP_Energy.v - pinN_Energy.v;
  v_power = pinP_Power.v - pinN_Power.v;
  v_output = pinP_Output.v - pinN_Output.v;

  0 = pinP_Energy.i + pinN_Energy.i;
  0 = pinP_Power.i + pinN_Power.i;
  0 = pinP_Output.i + pinN_Output.i;

  i_energy = pinP_Energy.i;
  i_power = pinP_Power.i;
  i_output = pinP_Output.i;

  p_energy = v_energy * i_energy;
  p_power = v_power * i_power;
  p_output = v_output * i_output;

  p_output = efficiency*(p_energy + p_power);
  i_output = i_energy + i_power;
  v_output = demandedVoltage;

  annotation (
  Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false, extent={{-100,-   100},{100,
        100}}), graphics), Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false,
      extent={{-100,-100},{100,100}}), graphics={
    Rectangle(
      extent={{-100,100},{100,-100}},
      lineColor={0,0,127},
      lineThickness=0.5,
      fillPattern=FillPattern.Solid,
      fillColor={215,215,215}),
    Line(
      points={{-100,100}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None),
    Line(
      points={{-100,100},{-100,-100},{100,-100},{100,100},{-100,100}},
      color={0,0,127},
      thickness=0.5,
      smooth=Smooth.None),
    Text(
      extent={{-68,60},{70,-66}},
      lineColor={0,0,0},
      textString="Hybrid
  DC
   Converter")}));
   end DCDC2;
```

If I test the converter using two simple constant current sources and one constant current load, I get again a singularity error. Dymola 2015 tells me, that there might be a not determinable ground, which shouldn't be the case.

```
model test2

Modelica_EnergyStorages.Sources.Loads.BooleanConstantCurrent
booleanConstantCurrent(I=40)
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{46,0},{26,20}})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-84,-40},{-64,-20}})));
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.BooleanConstant booleanConstant
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{66,0},{46,20}})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground1
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{26,-86},{46,-66}})));
ElectricalEnergyStorageSystem.Components.DCDC2 dCDC2_1(efficiency=1,
  demandedVoltage=15)
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-44,0},{-24,20}})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.ConstantCurrent constantCurrent(I=5) 
annotation (Placement(transformation(
    extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
    rotation=270,
    origin={-74,10})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.ConstantCurrent   constantCurrent1(I=15) 
annotation (Placement(transformation(
    extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
    rotation=270,
    origin={6,10})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground2
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-4,-40},{16,-20}})));
equation 
connect(booleanConstantCurrent.on, booleanConstant.y) annotation (Line(
  points={{45,10},{45,10}},
  color={255,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(booleanConstantCurrent.pin_n, ground1.p) annotation (Line(
  points={{36,0},{36,-66}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(dCDC2_1.pinP_Output, booleanConstantCurrent.pin_p) annotation (Line(
  points={{-34,20},{-34,76},{36,76},{36,20}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(booleanConstantCurrent.pin_n, dCDC2_1.pinN_Output) annotation (Line(
  points={{36,0},{36,-54},{-34,-54},{-34,0}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(constantCurrent1.p, dCDC2_1.pinP_Power) annotation (Line(
  points={{6,20},{-24,20},{-24,16}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(constantCurrent1.n, dCDC2_1.pinN_Power) annotation (Line(
  points={{6,0},{-24,0},{-24,4}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(constantCurrent.p, dCDC2_1.pinP_Energy) annotation (Line(
  points={{-74,20},{-44,20},{-44,16}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(constantCurrent.n, dCDC2_1.pinN_Energy) annotation (Line(
  points={{-74,0},{-44,0},{-44,4}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(constantCurrent1.n, ground2.p) annotation (Line(
  points={{6,0},{6,-20}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(ground.p, constantCurrent.n) annotation (Line(
  points={{-74,-20},{-74,0}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
annotation (uses(
  Modelica_EnergyStorages(version="3.2.1"),
  Modelica(version="3.2.1"),
  Buildings(version="2.0.0")),    Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio
      =false, extent={{-100,-100},{100,100}}), graphics));
end test2;
```

And the code results in the following model. (Constant current load is from the Modelica_EnergyStorages library)

[image]

Hope you can somehow help me with that issue! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note, you have declared `demandedVoltage` but you use `vehicleVoltage`. Furthermore, I've added a capacitor with capacity 1F and initial voltage of 10 V to port 1 and a resistor of 1 Ohm to port 2 (plus the two required ground pins). The model runs up to 0.5s in SimulationX 3.6.5 and gives the expected results. At 0.5 s there is a convergence error since the capacitor is discarged and the capacitor current diverges (as expected).

Comment: Just a comment...with Modelica one of the nice things about the underlying symbolic manipulation is that you can build a DC to DC converter that is "ideal".  This means no dynamics (e.g. capacitors) are necessary.  If you are interested in the details, let me know.

Comment: @MichaelTiller The model is incomplete as top-model. One needs to add components to the ports of the dc-dc converter. It is clear that one could add a constant voltage source to port 1 instead of a capacitor. Nevertheless, the application is clear from the word `vehicleVoltage`. So some charging/discharging effect looked appropriate to me in the test model. Furthermore, the test model is **more fun** this way. One gets the expected `sqrt`-characteristic for the voltage signal and the expected failure when the capacitor is discharged. The current diverges because of the constant power demand.

Answer (score 3):

The only small problem is that you have declared `demandedVoltage` but you use `vehicleVoltage`. Nothing else is wrong with your model.

Note: It would be better to include a minimal top-model for testing in the question.

I tested your model in a top-model `TestDCDC` together with a capacitor as power supply and a resistor as load in SimulationX 3.6.5.

The following picture shows the schematic of the test model.

[image: Schematic of the test model]

The results obtained with SimulationX are depicted in the following figure.

[image]

I also checked the equation system generated by SimulationX. It looks fine.

Dymola 2015 generates a wrong error message saying that there are two more variables than equations. You should issue a bug-report for this model to the producer of Dymola. Note, that the symbolic analysis of Modelica models is quite complicated and problems like that may happen. Usually the maintainer of the tool is grateful for a bug-report in this case.

**Discussion of the solution:**
The DCDC converter demands a constant power of `P=100W` from the capacitor and the initial voltage of the capacitor is `capacitor1.v.start=10 V`.
This gives an energy-time signal of

`W = C/2*(v.start)^2-P*time = 50Ws - 100W*time`

and the capacitor voltage signal results to

`capacitor1.v = 2*sqrt(W)/C = 2V/As * sqrt(50Ws-100Ws*time)`

At `time = 0.5s` the capacitor is empty and the current diverges.
SimulationX stops correctly with an error message at time=0.5.

Complete model for reproducing the results:

```
model TestDCDC
    model DCDC
        extends Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.TwoPort;
        parameter Real demandedVoltage;
        Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sensors.VoltageSensor sekVolt annotation(Placement(transformation(
            origin={80,0},
            extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
            rotation=270)));
        Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sensors.CurrentSensor currentSensor annotation(Placement(transformation(
            origin={-50,-30},
            extent={{-10,10},{10,-10}},
            rotation=270)));
        Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SignalCurrent signalCurrent annotation(Placement(transformation(
            origin={-50,30},
            extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
            rotation=270)));
        Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.ConstantVoltage constantVoltage(V=demandedVoltage) annotation(Placement(transformation(
            origin={50,30},
            extent={{-10,10},{10,-10}},
            rotation=270)));
        Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sensors.CurrentSensor currentSensor1 annotation(Placement(transformation(
            origin={50,-30},
            extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
            rotation=270)));
        Modelica.Blocks.Math.Division division annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{6,22},{-10,38}})));
        Modelica.Blocks.Math.Product product annotation(Placement(transformation(
            origin={30,8},
            extent={{8,-8},{-8,8}},
            rotation=270)));
        Modelica.Blocks.Math.Gain gain(k=-1) annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,22},{-36,38}})));
        Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sensors.VoltageSensor primVolt annotation(Placement(transformation(
            origin={-80,0},
            extent={{-10,10},{10,-10}},
            rotation=270)));
        equation
            connect(currentSensor.p,signalCurrent.n) annotation(Line(points={{-50,-20},{-50,-15},{-50,15},{-50,20}}));

            connect(constantVoltage.n,currentSensor1.p) annotation(Line(points={{50,20},{50,15},{50,-15},{50,-20}}));

            connect(signalCurrent.p,p1) annotation(Line(points={{-50,40},{-50,45},{-50,50},{-95,50},{-100,50}}));

            connect(currentSensor.n,n1) annotation(Line(points={{-50,-40},{-50,-45},{-50,-50},{-95,-50},{-100,-50}}));

            connect(constantVoltage.p,p2) annotation(Line(points={{50,40},{50,45},{50,50},{95,50},{100,50}}));

            connect(currentSensor1.n,n2) annotation(Line(points={{50,-40},{50,-45},{50,-50},{95,-50},{100,-50}}));

            connect(primVolt.n,n1) annotation(Line(points={{-80,-10},{-80,-15},{-80,-50},{-95,-50},{-100,-50}}));

            connect(primVolt.p,p1) annotation(Line(points={{-80,10},{-80,15},{-80,50},{-95,50},{-100,50}}));

            connect(sekVolt.p,p2) annotation(Line(points={{80,10},{80,15},{80,50},{95,50},{100,50}}));

            connect(sekVolt.n,n2) annotation(Line(points={{80,-10},{80,-15},{80,-50},{95,-50},{100,-50}}));


            connect(gain.y,signalCurrent.i) annotation(Line(
                points={{-36.7,30},{-41.7,30},{-38,30},{-43,30}},
                color={0,0,127}));

            connect(division.y,gain.u) annotation(Line(
                points={{-10.7,30},{-15.7,30},{-13.3,30},{-18.3,30}},
                color={0,0,127}));

            connect(currentSensor1.i,product.u2) annotation(Line(
                points={{40,-30},{35,-30},{25.3,-30},{25.3,-6.7},{25.3,-1.7}},
                color={0,0,127}));

            connect(sekVolt.v,product.u1) annotation(Line(
                points={{70,0},{65,0},{65,-6.7},{34.7,-6.7},{34.7,-1.7}},
                color={0,0,127}));

            connect(product.y,division.u1) annotation(Line(
                points={{30,16.7},{30,21.7},{30,34.7},{12.7,34.7},{7.7,34.7}},
                color={0,0,127}));

            connect(primVolt.v,division.u2) annotation(Line(
                points={{-70,0},{-65,0},{12.7,0},{12.7,25.3},{7.7,25.3}},
                color={0,0,127}));
        annotation(
            Icon(
                coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false),
                graphics={
                    Rectangle(
                        lineColor={0,0,127},
                        fillColor={215,215,215},
                        fillPattern=FillPattern.Solid,
                        lineThickness=0.5,
                        extent={{-100,100},{100,-100}}),
                    Line(
                        points={{-100,100}}),
                    Line(
                        points={{-100,100},{-100,-100},{100,-100},{100,100},{-100,100}},
                        color={0,0,127},
                        thickness=0.5),
                    Line(
                        points={{-100,-100},{100,100}},
                        color={0,0,127},
                        thickness=0.5),
                    Text(
                        textString="DC",
                        lineThickness=0.5,
                        extent={{-60,80},{0,20}}),
                    Text(
                        textString="DC",
                        lineThickness=0.5,
                        extent={{0,-20},{60,-80}})}),
            Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)));
    end DCDC;
    DCDC dcdc(demandedVoltage=10) annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-30,30},{-10,50}})));
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground1 annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-85,-5},{-65,15}})));
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor resistor1(R=2) annotation(Placement(transformation(
        origin={35,40},
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=-90)));
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground2 annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{0,-5},{20,15}})));
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Capacitor capacitor1(
        v(
            start=10,
            fixed=true),
        C=1) annotation(Placement(transformation(
        origin={-75,40},
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=-90)));
    equation
        connect(resistor1.p,dcdc.p2) annotation(Line(
            points={{35,50},{35,55},{15,55},{15,45},{-5,45},{-10,
            45}},
            thickness=0.0625));
        connect(resistor1.n,dcdc.n2) annotation(Line(
            points={{35,30},{35,25},{15,25},{15,35},{-5,35},{-10,
            35}},
            thickness=0.0625));
        connect(ground2.p,dcdc.n2) annotation(Line(
            points={{10,15},{10,20},{10,35},{-5,35},{-10,35}},
            thickness=0.0625));
        connect(dcdc.p1,capacitor1.p) annotation(Line(
            points={{-30,45},{-35,45},{-35,55},{-75,55},{-75,50}},
            thickness=0.0625));
        connect(dcdc.n1,capacitor1.n) annotation(Line(
            points={{-30,35},{-35,35},{-35,25},{-75,25},{-75,30}},
            thickness=0.0625));
        connect(ground1.p,capacitor1.n) annotation(Line(
            points={{-75,15},{-75,20},{-75,25},{-75,30}},
            thickness=0.0625));
end TestDCDC;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tobias. The fault mixing up the voltages is due to the fact that I changed the model a bit to post it here.
In fact, I had the singularity problem in Dymola which confused me.
Thank you for your help!